# Count number of entries of a minimum or maximum value of a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to count number of occurrences of minimum value or maximum in an array in JS and remove the elements from original one if number of occurrences are more than 2(example). For example, I have below object:

```
let data = [
    {name: 'DataSet01', Severity:'5'},
    {name: 'DataSet02', Severity:'3'},
    {name: 'DataSet03', Severity:'2'},
    {name: 'DataSet04', Severity:'2'},
    {name: 'DataSet05', Severity:'3'}
    {name: 'DataSet06', Severity:'2'}
];
```

Here, Severity is the key and it's value '2' is the minimum among all and it occurred 3 times and I want to remove all entries with severity 2 from original array (data).

So Updated object should look like :

```
let finaldata = [
    {name: 'DataSet01', Severity:'5'},
    {name: 'DataSet02', Severity:'3'},
    {name: 'DataSet05', Severity:'3'}
];
```

So far, I tried with filter to find minimum, slice but not able to get desired results on this one. Hope some one can help me on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `Math.max` and `Math.min` find the maximum and minimum serverity.
- Then using the max and min severity find their occurrences in `data`.
- Then filter `data` if these values are greater than `2`.

```js
const 
  data=[{name:"DataSet01",Severity:"5"},{name:"DataSet02",Severity:"3"},{name:"DataSet03",Severity:"2"},{name:"DataSet04",Severity:"2"},{name:"DataSet05",Severity:"3"},{name:"DataSet06",Severity:"2"}],
  maxSeverity = String(Math.max(...data.map((o) => o.Severity))),
  minSeverity = String(Math.min(...data.map((o) => o.Severity))),
  numMaxSeverity = data.filter((o) => o.Severity === maxSeverity).length,
  numMinSeverity = data.filter((o) => o.Severity === minSeverity).length;

let res = numMaxSeverity > 2 ? data.filter((o) => o.Severity !== maxSeverity): [...data];
res = numMinSeverity > 2 ? data.filter((o) => o.Severity !== minSeverity) : res;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `max and min value` and also keep `count of severity` in data array using `single loop` (code optimization); and then use `filter()` method to get the desired output.

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'DataSet01', severity:'6'},
    {name: 'DataSet11', severity:'6'},
    {name: 'DataSet10', severity:'6'},
    {name: 'DataSet09', severity:'5'},
    {name: 'DataSet02', severity:'3'},
    {name: 'DataSet03', severity:'2'},
    {name: 'DataSet04', severity:'2'},
    {name: 'DataSet05', severity:'3'},
    {name: 'DataSet06', severity:'2'}
];

const filterData = (data) => {
  let maxValue = minValue = parseInt(data[0].severity);
  const countMap = new Map();
  for (const obj of data) {
    const objSeverity = parseInt(obj.severity);
    if (maxValue < objSeverity) {
      maxValue = objSeverity;
    }
    if (minValue > objSeverity) {
      minValue = objSeverity;
    }
    countMap.set(obj.severity, (countMap.get(obj.severity) ?? 0) + 1);
  }

  return data.filter(value => {
    const severity = parseInt(value.severity);
    if ((severity === maxValue || severity === minValue)
        && countMap.get(value.severity) > 2) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(filterData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

And another approach:

```js
const data = [ {name: 'DataSet01', Severity:'5'}, {name: 'DataSet02', Severity:'3'}, {name: 'DataSet03', Severity:'2'}, {name: 'DataSet04', Severity:'2'}, {name: 'DataSet05', Severity:'3'}, {name: 'DataSet06', Severity:'2'} ];

function removeMinMax(arr,prop,n=1){
 const mm={m:["min","max"].map(mima=>""+Math[mima](...arr.map(d=>d[prop]))),c:[0,0,0]};
 arr.forEach(e=>mm.c[mm.m.indexOf(e[prop])+1]++); // count occurences
 mm.flt=mm.m.filter((_,i)=>mm.c[i+1]>=n); // decide whether to filter them out or not
 return arr.filter(e=>mm.flt.indexOf(e[prop])<0)
} 
console.log(removeMinMax(data,"Severity")); // remove all entries with MIN and MAX values
console.log(removeMinMax(data,"Severity",2)); // remove them only when they occur at least twice
```

The function `removeMinMax(arr,prop,n)` expects the array `arr` to be filtered, the property `prop` to be scanned for MIN and MAX values and `n`, the minimum count of elements with MIN and MAX values in `arr` for them to be removed.

Within `removeMinMax(arr,prop,n)` the object `mm` is used to control the filtering behaviour:

- `mm.m` is an array: `[min_value, max_value]`
- `mm.c` holds the counts for these values:
  `[count_of NON_min_or_max_values, count_of MIN_values, count_of_MAX_values]`
- `mm.flt` is the *actual* filter-array:
  only elements `e` of `arr` having `mm.flt.indexOf(e.[prop])<0` will remain in the `res`-array.